# Receiving server error when downloading fonts

Tags: font-face, content-security-policy

I am getting a series of server errors when trying to download fonts. In the Network tab of the Chrome debug tools I see the URL, type (font) and the status (500). I was wondering if there was something that I could look at that could tell me more about the 500 error. I am suspecting it has something to do with CSP. I have tried adding Content-Security-Policy: font-src *; ... but that didn't work. If I knew what was causing the server error I might be able to solve the issue?

Comment: Error messages would be helpful to understand your problem.